# Adding Blueprints to Flask seems to break logging

Tags: python-2.7, flask

In my Flask server app, I wanted to split up my routes into separate files so I used Blueprint. However this caused logging to fail within the constructor function used by a route. Can anyone see what I might have done wrong to cause this?

Simplified example ...

main.py ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
import logging.handlers
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

from my_routes import *

logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("flask.log",
    maxBytes=3000000, backupCount=2)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '[%(asctime)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

logging.debug("started app")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_v1_0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info("Starting server")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9000, debug=True)
```

my_routes.py ...

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        logging.debug("Class1.__init__()")   # This statement does not get logged
        self.prop1=11
    def method1(self):
        logging.debug("Class1.method1()")
        return self.prop1

obj1 = Class1()

api_v1_0 = Blueprint('api_v1_0', __name__)

@api_v1_0.route("/route1", methods=["GET"])
def route1():
    logging.debug("route1()")
    return(str(obj1.method1()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an instance of `Class1` in the global scope of module `my_routes.py`, so the constructor runs at the time you import that module, the `from my_routes import *` line in `main.py`. This is before your logging handler is configured, so there is nowhere to log at that time.

The solution is simple, move your import statement below the chunk of code that sets up the logging handler.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this.